# Can't order a dict using OrderedDict and sorted

Tags: python-3.x

```
dict = {'word1':8, 'word2':5, 'word3' : 15, 'word4' : 1}
sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
[('word4', 1), ('word2', 5), ('word1', 8), ('word3', 15)]
```

Ok that's what I want.

```
OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
OrderedDict([('word1', 8), ('word2', 5), ('word3', 15), ('word4', 1)])
```

That's not what I want.
I don't understand. What am I doing wrong ? Why is the OrderedDict not ordered as desired ?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the behavior you see. Running your code produces the expected output. What kind of environment are you running this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the code that you wrote,the same case is working for me.Maybe since you are using it in a shell based environment so the values are not getting saved or something

Here is a screenshot of the code along with the output that you expect
[image: Same code producing proper output]

Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: When you call the print method on the object, indeed the order is ok. When you jut output the variable in the shell, you see what I got. Testing with next(iter(order_dict.keys()) shows the dict is indeed ordered as desired. Thanks